# React Native: issue animating maskedview opacity

Tags: react-native

Hieverybody, in my react native app I'm trying to create a tinder clone, to achieve the effect of a flashy animated mask overlay that appears over the profile image when a user clicks a button (semi-transparent green overlay with heart icon and I'M IN text), and then vanishes, I use Reanimated 2 to create a cool opacity animation and two superimposed images, a masked one and a normal non-masked one.

The animation will make the masked view flash on the screen and then disappear, providing an engaging visual effect.

Issue: right now I see no animation at all when I run triggerAnimation...

My code:

```
import Animated, { useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle, withTiming, Easing, withSequence } from 'react-native-reanimated';

 const opacity = useSharedValue(0);

    const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
      return {
        opacity: opacity.value,
      };
    });
  
    const triggerAnimation = () => {
      opacity.value = withTiming(1, { duration: 500, easing: Easing.out(Easing.quad) }, () => {
        opacity.value = withTiming(0, { duration: 500, easing: Easing.out(Easing.quad) });
      });
    };

 <View style={{ width: '100%', height: 425, position: 'relative', backgroundColor: 'rgb(113, 223, 202)' }}>
               
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={triggerAnimation} style={{ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 2, width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
        <Animated.View style={[{ position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: '100%' }, animatedStyle]}>
          <MaskedView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            maskElement={
              <View style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5)',
              }}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcon name='heart'  style={{ fontSize: 300, color: 'black', marginTop: 3 }} />
                <Text style={{
                  fontSize: 110,
                  color: 'black',
                  fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: -50
                }}>
                  I'M IN
                </Text>
              </View>
            }
          >
            <FastImage
              style={{ flex: 1, borderRadius: 20 }}
              resizeMode="cover"
              source={{ uri: env.SPACE_URL + user.images[0] }}
            />
          </MaskedView>
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
       
                <FastImage
          style={{ position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: '100%', borderRadius: 20 }}
          resizeMode="cover"
          source={{ uri: env.SPACE_URL + user.images[0] }}
        />
        
    </View>
```